# Define topology of mesh in Paraview

Tags: mesh, connectivity, paraview, topology

I have a structured grid (a series of x,y,z coordinates) and would like to create a "closed" mesh along the (x,y) plane. With this I mean, that I would like there to be a face that joins the first and last point at every (x,y) plane such that the mesh has a cylindrical topology. Is there a way of doing this easily in Paraview?

Many thanks!
Marta

Comment: Is it possible to describe your problem with some sort of image cause I have a hard time to imagine what exactly you want to do here...

Comment: Thank you. Say you had a truncated cone. How do you ask Paraview to create faces on the truncated bit, so that it "closes" (thinking of an ice-cream cone, such that the ice-cream would not drip down)?

I will send you a pic when I am back at my computer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to give several solutions here.

**Mesh level**

- you may use the [parametric torus source](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkParametricTorus.html) to generate your mesh. This is a VTK class, at the ParaView level you can use the [SuperQuadric source](https://kitware.github.io/paraview-docs/latest/python/paraview.simple.Superquadric.html) to generate a torus, it will be triangulated though.
- you can also create a torus easily inside paraview using the [periodic angular filter](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkAngularPeriodicFilter.html).

**Analysis level**

- if you have a regular grid, the [Topology Toolkit](https://topology-tool-kit.github.io/) provides several topological data analysis related filters that have a periodic boundary support and may interest you.